# Using razor notation in a js scripting file to point to the correct image location

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a separate javascript file (*.js) that is included in my asp.net mvc4 view. In that js file I am using razor notation to get the path of an image like this:

```
@Url.Content("~/images/MyImages.gif")
```

but it is not working so how to obtain the correct path poiting to the image from js file if razor cannot be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use Razor in a javascript file (you can use it in the Javascript you place in your view).

**Option 1:**
You can pass the image path as a parameter to the javascript function.

**Option 2:**
Create an action method that returns a JSON object with a list of Image paths. This action should be called one time and stored in your Javascript code. Then you can access that list, doing a lookup for some id.